# Python Pytrends - The request failed: Google returned a response with code 429

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

I am trying to collect a large amount of data from Google Trends using `Pytrends` but keep on getting a `429 error`. How can I avoid this? Would it help to buy a proxy?
I tried free proxies available online and I kept getting the following error:

```
ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='trends.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?geo=US (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('timed out')))
```

Here's the code I tried:

```
from pytrends.dailydata import  get_daily_data
get_daily_data("AAPL", 2017, 1, 2017, 5, proxies=["http://35.169.156.54:3128"])
```

Comment: Is it better to add the code you tried to the post?

Comment: I added the code

Comment: What is your reason for using proxies at all?

Comment: I keep getting 429 errors. I thought proxies might solve the issue?

Comment: This is probably Google rate-limiting your IP - you have two options: 1. send fewer requests, 2. use an official Google API (which you probably have to pay for) to get much more of the trends data. I am not sure if (2) exists, but it probably does...
You _could_ buy as many proxies as you needed to get around the issue, but that seems very expensive depending on how much data you need

Comment: Google does not have an official API. Can I continue to send lots of requests using a proxy?

Comment: You could, but the proxies would also get rate limited. You would need many proxies in order to succeed in doing this kind of thing - you could also reduce your request speed (once rate-limited) to 1 per minute (this will probably work)

Comment: without adding proxies, above code work well for me.

Comment: Would a rotating proxy such as: https://free-proxy-list.net/rotating-proxy-pro.html work?

Comment: It _might_ - Google might have some extra detection for these sort of things and block them. The only way to know for sure is to test it. Equally, if someone else is doing the same thing on the proxies they will be similarly rate limited!

Answer (score 0):

(31/03/2023)
Google Just change Google trends portal. [info here](https://searchengineland.com/google-launches-new-google-trends-portal-394026)

To fix this error you can folow this post here :
[pytends-api-throwing-429-error-even-if-the-request-was-made-very-first-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75744524/pytends-api-throwing-429-error-even-if-the-request-was-made-very-first-time)

It's change some methode to use google cookies in *request.py* in pytrends package:

Change the 'get' to 'post' in line 88 like this:

`return dict(filter(lambda i: i[0] == 'NID', requests.get(`

to

`return dict(filter(lambda i: i[0] == 'NID', requests.post(`